# Network Render Fails when CPU is Pinned

Tags: networking, audio, video, cpu, performance

I have a Windows 10 computer (call it machine A) who is sharing a solid state drive over a local network (wired, with 1Gbps ethernet and switches). I have other machines on the network who are reading files from and writing files to this drive. There are oftentimes situations where I am running many CPU-intensive and GPU-intensive tasks simultaneously on machine A (for example, caching frames in After Effects, doing a cpu 3D render, a gpu 3D render, uploading files to a server within a virtual machine, and listening to music/playing a video). When this happens, I have noticed that occasionally (not very often) if I am also watching a video or listening to music, the audio will briefly become extremely laggy/choppy and sound horrendously distorted. The mouse cursor also lags badly (maybe 0.25 - 1 frame per second) and essentially the whole operating system is lagging. This can last for a few seconds up to a few minutes at a time. I assume this is because the CPU is just being slammed with so many multithreaded processes.

What's interesting is that, whenever this happens, sometimes renders on the other machines (who are reading/writing from/to the drive on machine A) immediately fail (this usually happens at the same time as the audio/video playback distortion). Usually I get some low level error claiming the the network drive is out of space when it actually isn't or part of the output file will simply not be written to disk and the render fails silently. It's not consistent.

I realize the number of tasks I'm giving machine A to handle simultaneously is extreme, but my curiosity lies with why this failure happens in the first place, not how to prevent it. Is it because the other machine is sending an IO request to machine A and because it is so busy, it's not able to handle it in time and causes the operation to fail? Is this an operating system level problem? Are there timeouts built into certain IO requests at a hardware level? **I am just trying to wrap my mind around why this happens.**

For reference, all machines are running Windows 10 version 1607. Machine A has 8 cores / 16 threads.

Comment: How are you sharing the drive? iSCSI? NFS? SMB? And is it the network which share which claims 'timeout', or 'drive full' (Incorrectly). Or even the renderer which does a write to disk and on its own claims 'drive full' when it fails, regardless of the reason why it fails?  Many different paths here.

Comment: @Hennes The drive is being shared through Windows 10 file sharing. So like this: https://i.imgur.com/PWkD5G4.png It is being shared through direct Ethernet cable connections: https://i.imgur.com/nImZLsT.png. The rendering program that is NOT on machine A (so the machine trying to access the drive located in the computer which is lagging) is the one claiming that the drive is full when the render fails. I get this error from within the program that is rendering.

Comment: @Hennes here's an example of the error I'm receiving: https://i.imgur.com/hfNniAs.png